# Part contents in TOC in two lines

Tags: table-of-contents, parts, titletoc

I have reached this:
[image]

To look like this:
[image]
So that the page number is in front of the title of the part and aligned with the other page numbers, and the title of the part is aligned with the part number.
Extra: Is it possible, for example, to have only "Part One" in \sc format?

Here is the code I got so far from other answers:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{fmtcount} % For part number in written form
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Numberstring{part}}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{\partname>\hspace{4pt}\thepart}{0pt}{\Large}

\titlecontents{part}
               [0cm]
               {\Large\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}}%
              {Part \thecontentslabel\bclap}
              {}%
               {\enspace\hfill\thecontentspage}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Title of Part One}
\chapter{chapter} 
\section{section}

\part{Title of Part Two}
\chapter{chapter} 
\section{section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. However to  have part name in small caps *and* boldface, you need  a font which has bold small caps. I used `garamondx` for this.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{fmtcount} % For part number in written form
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Numberstring{part}}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{\partname>\hspace{4pt}\thepart}{0pt}{\Large}

\titlecontents{part}
               [0cm]
               {\contentsmargin{0cm}\large\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}}%
              {\textsc{Part \thecontentslabel}\newline}
              {}%
{\hspace{\fill}\thecontentspage}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Title of Part One}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}

\part{Title of Part Two}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is interesting that with `\fill` the page number goes all the way to the second line. Clean answer, works well!

Comment: The reason is not \fill. It is that, at the end of the second mandatory argument (the arguments with contents label) there is a implicit argument, which is the part (or more generally the section) title, and the very last command applies to this argument (just like with titlesec  – but this is not well documented). The very last command here is `\newline`, so that `\hfill` is on this newline, after the title.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{fmtcount} % For part number in written form
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Numberstring{part}}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{\partname\hspace{4pt}\thepart}{0pt}{\Large}

\titlecontents{part}
[0cm]
{\protect\addvspace{15pt}}%
{\Large\textsc{Part \thecontentslabel}\newline\bfseries}%
{}%
{\Large\bfseries\hfill\thecontentspage\hspace*{-1.2pc}}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Title of Part One}
\chapter{chapter} 
\section{section}

\part{Title of Part Two}
\chapter{chapter} 
\section{section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your reply works well. I have chosen the other as it is cleaner on setting the page number on the second line! Thanks for your attention!