# Memoir: Part contents in TOC in two lines

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I need something similar to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320700/part-contents-in-toc-in-two-lines), that is the second line of the part should start directly at the left margin.

This is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength{\cftpartindent}{0em} 
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{0em} 
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\\}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{Part\space}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\part{Test}

\end{document}
```

But for some reason the title on the second line is indented:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather a fudge but it does seem to work for single line titles.

In your code change the redefinition of `\cftaftersnumb` according to the following, to be placed after your `\cftpartname` redefinition:

```
\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth{\mylength}{\cftpartfont \cftpartname} % Space for Part text
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\newline\mbox{\hspace{-\mylength}}}
```

This puts some negative space, corresponding to that used by the Part text, in front of the first line of the title to make it align with the left margin. To do so for all lines of a multi-line title would require significant work on the internals of `memoir`, which I am no longer up to.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. But why not assign `\mylength` to `\cftpartnumwidth`? This has the same effect here. (Well, actually I am getting a much more overfull hbox, but visually both solutions seem to be identical.)